# The equalizer turns the volume off

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am creating a music player and i am using Equalizer class to turn on or off the equalizer. This is the method i have for turning off the equalizer,
But when i call method eqalizerOFF() it also turns volume to zero.

```
public static void equalizerON() {
    if (myEq != null) {
        myEq.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

public void equalizerOFF() {
    if (myEq != null) {
        myEq.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What `Equalizer` class are you using?  I don't see `setEnabled()` in this one `android.media.audiofx.Equalizer`. Please show where you're declaring `myEq` and show your `Equalizer` class if it's something you've written. Also, it would help to restate and clarify your question.  "How can I turn off the equalizer without affecting volume?"

Comment: import android.media.audiofx.Equalizer;
myEq = new Equalizer(10, player.getAudioSessionId());      @Gary99

Comment: I can't answer your question.  I'm not familiar with Equalizer and I don't have time to research it.  I'm just giving suggestions on making your question so that someone might answer it.  So, edit your question to include the code.  Don't put code in comments.  Now that you show initializing `myEq`, what is `player`?  The more you show, the clearer your question & the more likely someone will answer. [mcve]